# TCPDF unable to save to folder?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a script taken from TCPDF examples I am trying to out put it to another folder but I am unable to. I have tried searching stackoverflow and have used the examples here but it doesnt seem to work for me. I have also tried it on my server and still the same error. I have tried placing the folder in the TCPDF folder also to see if it was path issue. 
below is a the sample from Their website

```
<?php
  require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

  // create new PDF document
  $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

  // set document information
  $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
  $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
  $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
  $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
  $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

  // set default header data
  $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
  $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

  // set header and footer fonts
  $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

  // set default monospaced font
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

  // set margins
  $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

  // set auto page breaks
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

  // set image scale factor
  $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

  // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
  if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
      require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
      $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------

  // set default font subsetting mode
  $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

  // Set font
  // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
  // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
  // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
  $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

  // Add a page
  // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
  $pdf->AddPage();

  // set text shadow effect
  $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

  // Set some content to print
 $pdf->Output('TestFolder/example_001.pdf', 'F');

?>

TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file:
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple rights issue to me.

1. Does the output folder exist?
2. Does your web server run as a different user to the folder where the site is hosted?

To provide a real solution, you need to provide more information about your web-server setup. Which web server do you use? Can you log in via a terminal?

Comment: I am using MAMP for my local server and 00webhosting for my live server. YEs the ouput folder exists

Answer (score 0):

I had rights issues too, after I installed TCPDF via composer. It still causes me issues every time I set set up new development environments.

TCPDF tries to write to its installation folder during execution. If that folder is not writable by your webserver, TCPDF will die.

Try:
`su
chmod -R g+w vendor/tcpdf
chown -R owner:apache vendor/tcpdf`

Substituting, of course, the folder, owner and apache values with the real values from your server.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that **your file('TestFolder/example_001.pdf')** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.